# Работа в toolbar

Tags: java, android, xml

Доброго времени суток. Требуется сделать меню в `toolbar`:

[image: toolbar]

Пока что получается не совсем то)

[image: toolbar_2]

В `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` пытаюсь установить текст, протестировать положение `textView`, ловлю NPE. Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать задуманное и убрать название приложения `Riddle`, может я неправильно начал, что через `menu.xml` делаю? Также в `menu.xml` нет выравнивания для элементов, идут один за одним, а тут оно нужно. Пробовал пихать элементы сразу в `toolbar.xml`, но там они получаются очень неказистые и растянутые, в `menu.xml` же все получаются красивые, но "неуправляемые".

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        TextView item = (TextView) menu.findItem(R.id.textview_balance);
        item.setText("test");

        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
}
```

**menu/main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/button_back"
        android:title="@string/button_back"
        android:icon="@drawable/button_back"
        yourapp:showAsAction="always" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_balance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/button_hint"
        android:title="@string/button_hint"
        android:icon="@drawable/button_hint"
        yourapp:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/button_nextlevel"
        android:title="@string/button_nextlevel"
        android:icon="@drawable/button_nextlevel"
        yourapp:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<include layout="@layout/toolbar" android:id="@+id/toolbar" />
```

**toolbar.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я предлагаю не использовать меню, а задать расположение `ImageButton`s в layout'е `Toolbar`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
>
  <LinearLayout
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/left_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_left"
        android:onClick="onClick"/>
    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/center_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:src="@drawable/dollars155"
        android:onClick="onClick"/>
    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/right_left_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:src="@drawable/question_sign"
        android:onClick="onClick"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/right_right_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_right_in_ring"
        android:onClick="onClick"/>
   </LinearLayout>
 </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Далее в `Activity` реализуйте метод `onClick()`:

```
public  void onClick(View view) {
    int id = view.getId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.left_button:
            // делайте то, что нужно
            break;
        case R.id.center_button:
            // делайте то, что нужно
            break;
        case R.id.right_left_button:
            // делайте то, что нужно
            break;
        case R.id.right_right_button:
            // делайте то, что нужно
            break;
    }

}
```

Comment: Как раз потихоньку допер методом тыка, что надо в доп. слой помещать и тут Ваш ответ) Подскажите, а для чего тут используется пустой `View`?

Comment: Чтобы при наличии свободного места отделить среднюю картинку от левой и двух правых.

Comment: Вы не могли бы подсказать возможные причины того, что `LinearLayout` растянут не на всю ширину `toolbar`? Слева виден отступ ([скрин](http://i85.fastpic.ru/big/2016/1018/31/a962ad15f3be4f460a704b3327ee6031.png)), хотя в разметке вроде нигде нету, код Ваш копировал.

Comment: Попробуйте убрать атрибут layout_weight у левого ImageButton

Comment: Без изменений..

Comment: У меня на планшете заметно подвинулось влево...

Comment: Да, стрелочка немного убегает влево, но сам слой `LinearLayout` так же и остается не на всю ширину `toolbar`, как на [скрине](http://i85.fastpic.ru/big/2016/1018/31/a962ad15f3be4f460a704b3327ee6031.png)

Comment: Это похоже настройки по умолчанию Toolbar. Добавьте в Activity toolbar.setPadding(0,0,0,0); toolbar.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0,0); или настройте атрибуты как в первом ответе http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31063962

Comment: `toolbar.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0,0);` решило проблему, спасибо большое) Если надо в `xml`, то прописать в свойствах `toolbar` `app:contentInsetStart="0dp"`

Answer (score 1):

По поводу текста в `toolbar` предлагаю заменить Ваш `textView` на

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/textview_balance"
    android:title="0"
    yourapp:showAsAction="always" />
```

Затем в onCreateOptionsMenu запомнить `menu`

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    this.menu = menu;
    return true;
}
```

И затем обращаться к нему:

```
menu.findItem(R.id.textview_balance).setTitle("155");
```

Отключить `title` в `toolbar` можно следующим образом:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Если же нужен текст по именно центру `toolbar`, то добавляется он внутрь него самого, т.к. он является `ViewGroup`. Например:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Center Title"
        android:gravity = "center"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

В принципе, никто не мешает задать иконки в `menu.xml`, а текст в `toolbar.xml`. Центрироваться в данном примере он будет по промежутку от левого края до первой иконки, заданной в `menu.xml`.

Comment: Спасибо. Подскажите, а как можно задать выравнивание? Как в данном случае надо слева - кнопка, центр - изображение + текст, справа - две кнопки.

Comment: @Pollux если нужен только порядок элементов, то это задается в main.xml. В качестве кнопки "назад" можно использовать `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);` Если же важно, чтобы текст бы по центру `toolbar`, то это задается toolbar.xml.

Comment: @Pollux обновил ответ.

Comment: Ну это применимо только если макс. размеры одного элемента, а если несколько, то каша получается. В принципе решаемо добавлением элементов в другой слой, например `RelativeLayout`, тогда выравнивание работает корректно.